# Cannot mount encrypted Time Machine

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, password, encryption

I've an encrypted Time Machine with the password saved on the keychain.
Now, trying to plug in, it ask me the password and it's always wrong.
I've checked hundreds of times and it also allowed me to change the password, but the disk won't mount.

I've tried to verify and then repair the disk from Disk Utility,
but after verified it shows me this message:

[image]

I can I solve this?

Update:

[image]

Update 2:

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture with all of the above text.

Comment: @FireCode Done.

Comment: In the sidebar the disks are displayed hierarchically. If you click the hierarchically higher level of this disk does the Repair Disk button become active?

Comment: @root yes, should I repair the disk from there?

Comment: Yes, start if from there.

Comment: @root I've added another screenshot. Now!??!

Comment: That obviously does not look good, can Time Machine access it at all now or is it still completely unable to open it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18515/discussion-between-albertopriore-and-root).

Comment: @root It is still completely unable to open...

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this way...
https://beshoy.girgis.us/2013/11/solved-error-disk-utility-cant-repair-disk-backup-many-files-possible/

Tried multiple times to repair the disk...

Comment: so after using disk utility several times, it finally -DID- repair it, sounds like. Thanks. That page takes FOREVER to load... mb running off his home machine.